# Problema para leer un formulario en Express.js

Tags: nodejs, formularios, express

estoy haciendo un formulario en Node.js con Express, Body-Parser y quiero mostrar en consola los datos al tocar el submit, pero al mandar los datos me tira el siguiente error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
>       at C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\src\index.js:31:37
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at serveStatic (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\socialred\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)

Este es mi formulario html:

```
<div id="register">
        <form action="/register" method="POST">
            <p>Nombre de usuario</p>
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
            <p>Email</p>
            <input type="email" name="useremail"/>
            <p>Contraseña</p>
            <input type="password" name="userpassword"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrarse"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Y aca el index.js

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  router=express.Router(),
  path= require("path"),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema(),
  userRegister = require("./models").User
```

;

```
app.set("port", process.env.port || 8080);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"/public")));
app.use("/", router);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

//ROUTES

router.get("/",function(req,res){
res.sendFile("index.html");
});

router.get("/register", function(req,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/register.html");
});

router.post("/register",function(req,res){
console.log("Nombre: "+req.body.username);
console.log("Email: "+req.body.useremail);
console.log("Contraseña: "+req.body.userpassword);
});

router.get("/login", function(req,res){
res.sendFile("login.html");
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), function(req,res){
console.log("Server listen on port: ", app.get("port"));
});
```

Quien pueda ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Hola, por más que intento replicar el error no lo consigo. Me funciona de maravillas la parte esencial de tu código. He usado `body-parser` y he usado los métodos nativos de Express ([`json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) y [`urlencoded()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded)) son parte de Express 4.16.x) y me funciona sin problemas. No sabría la causa de tu error. ¿Qué versión de Express usas?

Comment: Se me ocurre que revises las cabeceras que recibes cuando haces la solicitud POST de tu formulario, tal vez es un tema de que falta la cabecera `Content-Type`. Puedes hacer un `console.log(req.headers);` en tu ruta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder Mauricio! Mi version de express es "express": "^4.17.1". cuando muestro los headers me sale como un [object Object]